# Can a DSP (digital signal processor) be used as a datalogger?

Tags: signal-processing, microcontroller

For my project, I would need to develop a data logger able to read data (images) from a USB camera and store them on a micro SD card. The power consumption of this datalogger should be very low. I found some microcontroller with the features that I need. For example http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430f5529 but, during my researches, I've also found some DSPs.

I know that DSPs are more for signal processing, but I've read that nowadays the difference between a DSP and a microcontroller, in terms of performance, is very small.

My question is: can a DSP (such as  http://www.ti.com/product/TMS320C5535/datasheet) be used for this purpose? Or a standard Micro controller would be better?

Thank you.

Comment: A DSP will work, a microcontroller will work.  As for which will work better, that depends on the specific features of each and what you want the system to be capable of.  So we can't really answer for you...

Answer (score 1):

A **DSP** will do for sure the work, consider that **DSPs** are intended to be implemented on Signal Processing applications this menas asweel in the background that DSP are able to perform complex floating point operations at a very low cycle rate, 'modulo' or 'wrapping' addressing operations, 'buffer start', 'buffer end' register, reverse-carry flag etc etc

At the end your question means for me something like you are asking suggestions to buy either an Iphone-8 or a Nokia 3210 only to send sms :) missing the high purpose and performance of the device....

A very "normal" μController with an 10 bits ADC could do the job too... both can be implementened in a very low current consumption and are very straight forward to be flashed